# Android switched into strange alternate user mode, does not react to input anymore as usual

Tags: settings

My Android phone is stuck in some strange user mode, and this does not vanish after reboot.

- I am seeing green boxes around icons
- It is not responsive anymore
- I do not see how to open options

What is happening here, and how to switch it off? Even better, how do I remove this "feature" completely?

Comment: Can you do a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out, so I am posting the answer for reference.

I accidentally switched on *Talkback*.

To switch it off, I had to push the volume up and down buttons for 3 seconds simultaneously.

Switching the feature on and off via the two volume buttons can (presumably) be disabled in the menu, and that should be somewhere in the *Accessibility* or something similar section.